# Qual a origem da expressão: "Onde está um machiqueiro está um engenheiro!"?

Tags: português-europeu, origem-histórica, origem, regionalismo

Qual a origem da expressão: "Onde está um machiqueiro está o engenheiro!"?
Oiço muito na  ilha da Madeira

Comment: E eu nem tenho ideia do que seja um machequeiro.

Comment: Um Machiqueiro é um natural ou habitante de [Machico](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machico), um município da ilha da Madeira.

Comment: Oiço?  É uma variante de ***ouço*** usada na Madeira?

Comment: @Centaurus, é uma [variante](https://dicionario.priberam.org/Conjugar/ouvir) aceite em Portugal; mas é mais comum "ouço". Como touro/toiro, ouro/oiro, mouro/moiro, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um Machiqueiro é um natural ou habitante de [Machico](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machico), um município da ilha da Madeira.

---

Uma pessoa da Madeira respondeu-me que o significado de «onde está um machiqueiro está um engenheiro»:

> É mais ou menos: O machiqueiro desenrasca-se. Até para pôr o motor da lancha a trabalhar...

Comment: desenrasca-se?  O que significa? Seria o mesmo que "se vira"?  Ou "é muito safo"?   Ou "manda bem em qualquer situação"?

Comment: @Centaurus, é uma palavra um bocado complexa... é uma _muito_ boa pergunta para abrires. :) Mas estar "[à rasca](https://dicionario.priberam.org/%C3%A0%20rasca)" é estar enrascado. [Desenrascar](https://dicionario.priberam.org/desenrascar)-se é fazer-se deixar de estar enrascado. Safar-se (de uma situação chata ou complicada ou...). Explicaria talvez assim: *um cara desenrascado se vira facilmente; é agil a se desemaranhar das complicações da vida; de biscate faz trabalho*. *Se vira*, sim acho que sim. *Muito safo*, nem por isso. *Manda bem*, não.

Comment: Entendi.  Estar à rasca não é comum por estas bandas, mas já ouvi "desta vez vou mesmo à rasca, vou me pirar de mansinho"  em uma canção portuguesa.

Comment: Lembrei que aqui é comum "ele está enrascado" ou "numa enrascada".